# Gradle task for Java playground

Tags: java, gradle, docker

I am still new to Docker and Gradle, but I am trying to setup a Gradle build that builds a Docker image.

I just finished setting up a `Dockerfile` which locally deploys and runs the jar as expected. I have this in my `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'se.transmode.gradle:gradle-docker:1.2'
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow' version '1.2.3'
}

apply plugin: 'docker'

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.myapp.Main'
    }
}


task buildDocker(type: Docker, dependsOn: shadowJar) {
    push = false

    applicationName = jar.baseName

    tagVersion = 'latest'
    dockerfile = file('src/main/docker/Dockerfile')

    copy {
        from shadowJar
        into stageDir
    }
}
```

I run `./gradlew build buildDocker` to build the image. I am happy with this so far.

Usually I create a throwaway class (e.g. `Playground.java`) with a `main` method that I can run and disregard. Usually I just run this in the IDE, but now I would like to be able to connect to the other Docker containers that I know will be running.

I know I could try changing the `sourceSets` I'm using by excluding `com.myapp.Main`, but I was imagining there might be a more elegant solution resembling this:

```
task buildDockerPlayground(type: Docker, dependsOn: shadowJar) {
    main = 'com.myapp.Playground'

    push = false

    applicationName = jar.baseName

    tagVersion = 'latest'
    dockerfile = file('src/main/docker/Dockerfile')

    copy {
        from shadowJar
        into stageDir
    }
}
```

Another approach might be to have another task that I use to replace `build` when I call `./gradlew build buildDocker`, e.g. `./gradlew playground buildDocker`. Is this more practical?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest replacing your hard coded main class with a gradle project property.

```
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': main
    }
}
```

Set that default property in your `gradle.properties` file.

```
main=com.myapp.Main
```

Finally, when you need to build your docker container that uses a jar running 
`com.myapp.Playground` you can invoke gradle with:

```
./gradlew buildDocker -Pmain=com.myapp.Playground
```

Edit: To achieve the same thing in a task

```
project.ext.main = 'com.myapp.Main'

task play(){
    project.main = 'com.myapp.Playground'
    finalizedBy buildDocker
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': project.main
    }
}
```

Comment: I like the suggestion for removing the hard-coded attribute. Is there a way to set the `main` through a task? For example, a way to define a task `playground` that uses `build` and changes `main` before running `build`?

Comment: Also, docker is using the cached `COPY` layer with the app until I run `./gradlew build buildDocker` a second time. The same applies to when I use the `-P` flag. I am not using the `inputs` or `outputs` properties in the `buildDocker` task yet. Why might Docker not detect/reflect this change the first time?

Comment: I edited my answer to include achieving the same thing in a task. Unfortunately, the docker layering issue is outside the scope of this question and my knowledge. This has been a gradle issue.

Comment: For some reason the layering issue is no longer present with the task version of the solution.